# How to convert Range Int Array to String Array in Swift efficiently?

Tags: ios, swift, string, int, uipickerview

I create a range of in from 1-100 doing this:

```
let array = [Int](1...10)
```

Now how do I convert that into a String array as I need it for UIPickerView

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

You can directly `map` an `Int` range to a `String` array

```
let stringArray = (1...10).map(String.init)
```

Answer (score 1):

Well you can do it like :

```
let formattedArray = ([0,1,1,0].map{String($0)}).joined(separator: ",")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 var arr = [1,2,3]

 let strArr = arr.map{String($0)}
```

OR
 in picker you may return the component title like this

```
 func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, titleForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int) -> String! {
    return  "\(arr[row])"
 }
```

Comment: When I do that I get this: 
{"Cannot use instance member 'arr' within property initializer; property initializers run before 'self' is available"}
When put change the variables to "lazy var arr" it wont work with the UIPickerView

Comment: You need to call map inside viewDidLoad

Answer (score 0):

If it is just a sequence of strings "1", "2", .. you can simply get it using `map`:

```
let model = array.map { "\($0)" }
```

If you are looking for spelled out numbers, such as "one", "two", ..., use number formatter:

```
let numberFormatter: NumberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.spellOut
let model = array.map { numberFormatter.string(from: NSNumber(value: $0)) ?? "" }
```